# Newbie to linux confused about how to install packages not in the repositories

Tags: software-installation, path

I've installed Firefox-developer and Telegram for Ubuntu. Firefox comes along with many files, not just a binary file. Telegram comes with the binary plus an 'updater'.

This is more generally that for any program not in the repos we either include a repo or download a file from the web. This is the case with firefox developer, telegram, sometimes google chrome, etc.

What I'm doing so far, is to include the full folders under `~/bin` - firefox complains if I don't keep the relative paths the same - and added those complete folders to the `PATH` variable. To make it clear it looks like this:

is to add each full path to the binaries to the `PATH`. For example, this line is on my `~/.bashrc`

```
export PATH="$PATH:~/bin/firefox-dev/firefox-bin:/~/bin/Telegram/Telegram"
```

But this is likely not the right way? Can anyone please give me a hint on this?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really one "right" way to do this. There are multiple valid ways, and which one you choose will depend on what your ultimate intent is. You mention you're a "newbie", so this confusion is normal - as you gain experience, you'll gain insight into which ways are better for you. For the most part, though, there are the following options:

1. Install as you have been doing, into your home directory. This is most useful for when you want to make temporary use of a new program, or when you have an NFS home directory and you want to "take your programs with you" when you log in to a different machine with the same NFS home directory.
2. Install to a system-local location, such as `/usr/local/`. This is useful for when you want all users on a system to be able to access a given program, but you don't want it in the traditionally more controlled `/usr/` directories. Typically this method will require `sudo` or other superuser privileges.
3. Install to a system location, such as `/usr/`. This is the converse to #2, where you do want the system in the mroe controlled system-wide location (e.g. `/usr/bin/programname` to run the program. Also typically requires `sudo` or other superuser privileges.

Ask five different people, and you'll likely get five different opinions on where you should install these programs. Many come with instructions that assume you want them installed to a specific location, some don't work very well (if at all) when not installed to where they expect to be installed.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry that I can't upvote with less than 15, but hopefully we'll get there. For the method 1, I should place the whole folder in the ~/bin ? That's what I fear of / unsure of...

Comment: When I'm following method 1, I typically put the distribution folder somewhere under `~` and then create a symlink to the binary under `~/bin`. Putting the whole distribution folder under `~/bin` is completely acceptable.

Comment: I put such stuff in `/opt` and create a symlink to the binary in question to `/usr/local/bin/foo`. This way the binary is in `$PATH` without further ado but the program in question is still contained in a folder I may eventually `rm` in one go when no longer needed (or needs an update).